# Reading a manipulating text files variable suggestion

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# and am working on a fun maybe useful program for my education.
I've got data that's stored in files, one file for each entry in the below format. I believe the are in a particular order in the file as well.
There are around a 100 values for each file. My program will basically alter a few of these
values and write them back to the file.

I'm trying to figure out how I should store these values. I know how to read the text file.
I thought about reading each line and storing it in an array. Does anyone have any other suggestions? Would this be a good use case for a class?

```
D:"value1"=00000800
D:"value2"=00000001
S:"value3"=full
```

Comment: Welcome zarethustra! Is it possible to show us some code of what you did? It would be easier for us if we just modify your code rather that write a whole new one for you.

Comment: I actually hadn't written any code yet. I was still in the design phase. I can re-post once I do. It looks like I might have jumped the gun.

Comment: The answer would much depend on how you intend to process each file (or the union of all files). If you are simply searching for a value across one or more files, there is no need to use arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glad you have picked up C#. I hope you find learning it rewarding.

One of the methods I prefer when I want to modify a file in C# is first [`File.ReadAllLines`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=netframework-4.8) and then [`Files.WriteAllLines`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealllines?view=netframework-4.8). For these two *static* methods, you will need `using System.IO`.

To parse the texts, you might need [`String.Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Split_System_Char___).

Here's an example:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var filepath = @"myfile.txt";

        // Read all lines.
        var allLines = File.ReadAllLines(filepath);

        // Modify your text here.
        foreach (var line in allLines)
        {
            // Parse the line and separate its components with delimiters ':', '"' and '='.
            var components = line.Split(new char[]{':', '"', '=',});
            // Change all X:"value_i"=Y to X:"value_i"=5.
            components[2] = "5";
        }

        // Write all lines.
        File.WriteAllLines(filepath, allLines);
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be nice to mention that you have decided that the delimiters to be ":", "=" and the quotes since the OP did not specify this.